# How do I configure a WebSecurityExpressionHandler with Spring security?

Tags: spring, security, taglib

I had a project that was working ok with Spring 3.0. I've now moved to Maven to control dependencies and moved to Spring 3.1.2 jars and Spring security 3.1.1 jars.

When I attempt to access a JSP that includes use of the security taglib (eg ) I get the error below:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.io.IOException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in JSP 'authorize' tags.
```

In my security-context I have:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired"
```

From my old project:

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

I couldn't find that class in the packages I have for my project, so thinking it may just be a move of classes I tried:

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

This gives me the same error.

Spring-security dependencies I have configured at the moment:
spring-security-core-3.1.1
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.1
spring-security-acl-3.1.1
spring-security-config-3.1.1
spring-security-web-3.1.1

Am I missing a jar that would contain whatever 'use-expressions=true' needs?

Comment: So it seems WebSecurityExpressionHandler ahas been removed in Spring 3.1.1, which would explain why my application can't find an instance.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1985

Though now I'm even more lost as presumably there is something I need to replace that functionality but I don't know what.

Comment: It has been fixed, but I couldn't tell you how/why. It stopped complaining after a bunch of changes. 

I'll add an answer in a minute....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since made a number of changes to my project and I'm not 100% sure which actually fixed this issue but the most likely contenders listed below:

- There were some 3.0 jars hidden away in a lib folder of my app. Removed them manually.
- Removed the expressionHandler definition from security-context altogether
- changed the URL mapping style thus:

  ```
  <!-- Spring Security < 3.1
  These were inside the <http... > element
  <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/loggedOut" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/include/css/**" filters="none"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/include/img/**" filters="none"/>
  -->
  ```

  Changed to the follow BEFORE the  element in security-context:

  ```
  <!-- for Spring-security >= 3.1 -->
  <http pattern="/public/**" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/loggedOut" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/include/css/**" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/include/img/**" security="none"/>
  ```

My  element now reads:

```
        <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" create-session="ifRequired" access-denied-page="/accessDenied" >
```

I hope this helps someone else with similar issues moving from Spring security 3.0 -> 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true,
We are using intercept url to control role access, but you omit them.